# How to make the Figure Caption “Figure 1.5” bold in Tufte Latex?

Tags: captions, tufte

Unfortunately the standard options like

```
 \usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
```

Do not work with the tufte-class because

*Package caption Warning: \caption will not be redefined since it's already
(caption) redefined by a document class or package which is
(caption) unknown to the caption package.*

Is there any other possibility to get a caption like

**Figure 1.5** The Caption Text

Instead of

Figure 1.5 The Caption Text

in the tufte-latex class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adopt this trick.

Declare

```
\setcaptionfont{\bfseries}
```

and then in your captions add `\mdseries` like in

```
\caption{\mdseries Text}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\setcaptionfont{\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{\mdseries Text}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]